# How to refresh cart and checkout in every 5 seconds in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am working on WordPress / WooCommerce

My requirement is when the customer is on the **CART** page, I want to refresh CART **every 5 seconds**, **without page load**.

For eg: If the customer has added 1 product to the cart and the price is ₹8.00

Later on, Admin changes the price for the product from ₹8.00 to ₹10.00

How can I show the latest price without page refresh?

I am using this code, but not working

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
        function refresh_fragments() {
            console.log('fragments refreshed!');
            $( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_fragments_refreshed' );
        }
        refresh_fragments();
        setInterval(refresh_fragments, 5000);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I would suggest to run this only if you update product and price is changed. This could lead to alot cpu drain if there are more visitors. Just keep that in mind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below code. instead of using the `wc_fragments_refreshed` trigger, you can trigger the update cart button.

**Cart refresh.**

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';
    jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
        function refresh_fragments() {
            console.log('fragments refreshed!');
            jQuery( "[name='update_cart']" ).removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            jQuery( "[name='update_cart']" ).trigger( 'click' );
        }
        setInterval(refresh_fragments, 5000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**UPDATE** as per OP request.

**Checkout Refresh.**

Use `update_checkout` trigger.

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';
    jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
        function refresh_fragments() {
            $( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
        }
        setInterval(refresh_fragments, 5000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hi , Your answer is working for me. 
How do I do the same for the checkout page also ?

Comment: jQuery( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_fragment_refresh' ); Only this worked for me.